# How get the widthPoint in itext7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In the previous version of **itext (5.5.x)** I used the `BaseFont` class as follows:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont ("Arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, true);
```

Then used the method `getWidthPoint`

```
bf.getWidthPoint (TEXT_EXAMPLE, fontSize);
```

But in the version of **itext 7** I am not finding the `BaseFont` class and also some utility that allows me to get the withPoint of a certain text.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a similar font in `iText7`, use:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("Arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

To get the width of a certain `String`, use:

```
float width = font.getWidth(TEXT_EXAMPLE, fontSize);
```

Comment: It's not about creating font, it is about calculating the witdthPoint. WidthPoint is different to Width

Comment: Apologies, you're totally right. My mistake. Your answer is correct!

Comment: Okay, I'm glad we hit on the common ground :)